Shifting strip plot next to half violin plot in seaborn
I'm trying to shift the points to the left of the violin plot.
How can I achieve this?
Here is an example code:
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.violinplot(np.random.random(100), inner=None,
                    bw_method=.1,fill=True,)
sns.stripplot(np.random.random(100),
              edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5, palette=['lightblue'] * 3, ax=ax)



You can provide an array of repeated x-values to position both.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(200).cumsum()
ax = sns.violinplot(y=data, x=np.full_like(data, 1.5), inner=None, orient='v',
                    bw_method=.1, fill=True)
sns.stripplot(y=data, x=np.full_like(data, 1), jitter=True, orient='v',
              edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5, color='lightblue', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()


PS: The jitter= parameter of sns.stripplot can also be a value to change the width, e.g jitter=0.3.
